# Why does an iOS Certificate exported from the Mac Keychain includes a sibling certificate that was not included in the export action?

Tags: ios, macos, ssl, certificate, keychain

Here is what I'm experiencing and the steps I performed:

- I created 2 new apps in the iOS provisioning portal each with APNS enabled
- Using the same certificate signing request I created pushA.cer and pushB.cer files
- I downloaded the two .cer files and installed them into my keychain (each had private key association and were injected individually)
- I then exported pushA/pk as a pushA.p12
- Then I imported the pushA.p12 into a separate computer's keychain

Upon doing this I noticed that pushB/pk along with pushA/pk were inserted into the new Keychain.

I opened the .p12 file which contained both Certificates both with the same localKeyID...Output below

```
MAC Iteration 1
MAC verified OK
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2048
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: Apple Production IOS Push Services: ######
    localKeyID: ######
subject=######
issuer=/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations/CN=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
######
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: #####
    localKeyID: #####
subject=#####
issuer=/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations/CN=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
#######
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 2048
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: #####
    localKeyID: #####
Key Attributes:
```

I have generated many apple certificates before and have never seen this. I would like to know why this is happening ? or What I did to make this happen?

NOTE: The export of pushA goes as expected if I remove pushB from the keychain and then export and vice versa.

Comment: have you able to figure this out?

Comment: or at least to know which is which?